Pagination in my SwiftUI, Firebase project
I am trying to implement pagination in my project and it keeps getting stuck in the loading ProgressView(), i have tried to fix it and can't place my finger on where i am going wrong. Below are both my ViewModel and my View, all help is welcome. Thanks.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase


class SportNewsViewModel: ObservableObject {

 @Published var sport = [SportNews]()
        private let pageSize = 5 // Adjust the page size as needed
        private var lastDocument: DocumentSnapshot?
        private var isFetching = false

        func fetchSportNews() {
            fetchSportNewsBatch()
        }

        func fetchNextPageOfSportNews(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            guard !isFetching else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            fetchSportNewsBatch(completion: completion)
        }

        private func fetchSportNewsBatch(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
            isFetching = true
            var query = Firestore.firestore().collection("sportNews").order(by: "uid", descending: true)
            if let lastDocument = lastDocument {
                query = query.start(afterDocument: lastDocument)
            }
            query.limit(to: pageSize).getDocuments { [weak self] snapshot, error in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching sport news: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    self.isFetching = false
                    completion?(false)
                    return
                }

                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                    print("Snapshot is nil")
                    self.isFetching = false
                    completion?(false)
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let newSport = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> SportNews? in
                        let sportTime = document["sportNewsTime"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
                        let date = sportTime.dateValue()

                        return SportNews(
                            id: document.documentID,
                            uid: document["uid"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsImage: document["sportNewsImage"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsTitle: document["sportNewsTitle"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsPreview: document["sportNewsPreview"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsTopBar: document["sportNewsTopBar"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsType: document["sportNewsType"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsAuthor: document["sportNewsAuthor"] as? String ?? "",
                            sportNewsTime: sportTime,
                            sportNewsArticle: document["sportNewsArticle"] as? String ?? "",
                            thumbsUp: document["thumbsUp"] as? Int ?? 0,
                            unthumbsUp: document["unthumbsUp"] as? Int ?? 0,
                            thumbsDown: document["thumbsDown"] as? Int ?? 0,
                            unthumbsDown: document["unthumbsDown"] as? Int ?? 0
                        )
                    }
                    self.sport.append(contentsOf: newSport)
                    self.isFetching = false
                    self.lastDocument = snapshot.documents.last
                    completion?(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

The View, i am looking at loading 5 items everytime a user swipes up, the logic is clear but i am having a hard time figuring it out.
import SwiftUI

struct SportNewsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sportViewModel = SportNewsViewModel()
    @State private var isEndReached = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(sportViewModel.sport) { sport in
                    NavigationLink(destination: SportNewsDetailView(sport: sport)) {
                        SportNewsRowView(sport: sport)
                    }
                }
                if isEndReached {
                    Text("You've reached the end")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .padding()
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                        .onAppear {
                            fetchNextPageIfNeeded()
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.bottom, 50)
        }
        .onAppear {
            sportViewModel.fetchSportNews()
        }
    }
        init() {
            sportViewModel.fetchSportNews()
        }
          private func fetchNextPageIfNeeded() {
                guard !isEndReached else { return }
                let lastVisibleIndex = sportViewModel.sport.count - 1
    
                if lastVisibleIndex >= 0 && lastVisibleIndex == sportViewModel.sport.count - 1 {
                    sportViewModel.fetchNextPageOfSportNews { success in
                        isEndReached = !success
                    }
                }
            }


        }


When you want the View struct to own the object it's @StateObject not @ObservedObject otherwise the object is being lost every time the View struct is init on every state change in the parent View. Objects are hard to get right so you can avoid them completely if you upgrade to .task for your async logic.

Remove DispatchQueue.main.async as it's not needed within Firebase calls. UI is always done on the main thread and networking is done in the background.
